# Using aliases in my WSL command line

Tags: bashrc, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to launch Atom text editor from my WSL bash.exe. I found [this](https://medium.com/@heinrich10/launching-windows-application-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl-60cc2c165029) manual

And did exactly as it advises, but it doesn't work. I also find in .bashrc file this comment:

```
# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.
```

Then I created file .bash_aliases and added this command in it

```
alias atom=’/mnt/c/Windows/System32/cmd.exe /c “atom”’
```

In both cases the call of the `atom` alias produces this output:

```
    grep: /etc/wsl.conf: No such file or directory
net.js:200
    this._handle.open(options.fd);
                 ^

Error: EINVAL: invalid argument, uv_pipe_open
    at new Socket (net.js:200:18)
    at createWritableStdioStream (internal/process/stdio.js:164:16)
    at process.getStdout [as stdout] (internal/process/stdio.js:14:14)
    at console.js:246:38
    at NativeModule.compile (bootstrap_node.js:596:7)
    at Function.NativeModule.require (bootstrap_node.js:541:18)
    at setupGlobalConsole (bootstrap_node.js:310:41)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:70:7)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

Comment: What happens without the alias? E.g, `/mnt/c/Windows/System32/cmd.exe /c “atom”`

Comment: It's saying that it's trying to run `grep`, but `/etc/wsl.conf: No such file or directory` the `/etc/wsl.conf` file that it needs does not exist.

Comment: I don't think it's wise to try to launch a GUI from WSL bash

Comment: mcidub@ll:~$ /mnt/c/Windows/System32/cmd.exe /c “atom”
'“atom”' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Launch windows apps from windows

Comment: Its a native feature for WSL to launch windows apps from bash. On the 11:55 sec from the  second video from this page - https://tinyurl.com/y878ny6c Rich Turner talks about this.

Comment: Your alias has curly quotes. Is that a typo? It should be this: `alias atom='/mnt/c/Windows/System32/cmd.exe /c "atom"'`